# Install CentOS 7 on N54L

Tags: linux, centos, hardware, installation

currently Im using Scientific Linux 7.2 on my HP Microserver N54L.

To get more "mainstream" and out of curiosity (and to try out my ansible-playbooks), I wanted to install CentOS 7 on it.

So I downloaded the current iso-image, dd'd it on my usb drive and bootet from it, but after selecting "Check disk & Install" or only "Install", I get several errors. These happen directly afterwards.

Please look at [this error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meUIm.jpg) The difference is the following boot parameter:

```
initcall_blacklist=clocksource_done_booting
```

I got it from [this bug report](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=9860)

I have no idea, how to approach the problem.

The same usb drive works fine on my laptop.

kind regards,
pwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out myself:

I installed CentOS 7.0 (I tried 7.1 and 7.2 before) and updated to the latest version.

But additionally, a reboot with Kernel

```
3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64
```

wasnt successfull, until I added

```
initcall_blacklist=clocksource_done_booting
```

with grubby.

kind regards,
pwe